# Search a specific line for a value within a range. Unix bash script

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I'd like to jump to a specific line in a file, line 33866. If the third number in this line is within the range -10 and +10 then I'd like to print the entire next line, 33867, to a file and stop.

If it isn't then it should look at line 67893 (difference of +34027), now if its in the range - print the next line and stop.

This should continue, next looking at line 101920 (difference of +34027) and so on until it finds a value in that range or reaches the end of the file.

Now regardless of whether or not that printed anything I need it to repeat the process but at a new starting line, this time the new start line is 33869 (difference 3), to print line 33870 to the same file.
Ideally, it would repeat n times, n being a read value input by the user when the script is ran.

Please stop me right there if this is too much to ask and I'll go back to banging my head against the wall and searching around the net for how to make this work on my own. Also let me know if I'm going about this the wrong way by trying to jump to a specific line and should search for the line by another means.
Any input greatly appreciated!

Edit:
Here is an example of the two lines being handled:

```
    17.33051021          18.02125499          30.40520932
    1.776579372         -23.74037576          12.48448432
```

with the first number starting in column 6, the second number starting in 26 and third in 46. (if minus is ignored I don't think it will matter)

Answer (score 2):

reading your question, I guess your file could be pretty big. Also I assume "the 3rd number" is 3rd field. so I come up with this one-liner:

```
awk -v l=33866 -v d=34027 'NR==l&&$3>=-10&&$3<=10{p=1;next}p{print;exit}{l+=d}' file
```

you just need to change the two arguments (`l (first line No. you need to check)` and `d (difference)`).

After found the right line to print, awk stops processing further lines in your file.

- didn't test, if there were typoes, sorry, but it shows my idea
- you should give some example input etc. i.e. the 3rd number, what is that? the 3rd field? or like `aa bb 2 dfd 3 asf 555`, the `555`?
- another one, actually you should show what you have done for your problem

Comment: I think this is going to work, so thanks so far. When testing the code hangs for a while, crunching through the big file. Is it possible to add a loop in front to look for the next one when its finished, i.e change l by +3 (without doing this manually)?

Comment: @sparxwil  if your requirement is, you have different `l-d` pairs to check, but you want to do the check by processing the file only once. It depends on your file size. If you could put all lines in memory (in an array), you could achieve your goal. otherwise, after one run, you have to process the file from beginning for a newly given `l` and `d`. Another idea is, you process the file once, and pick the 3rd columns for each line out, to a new file, as an "index file" (kind of). and you just need to check this file, and target the line number to print. I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: @sparxwil also for the `l` and `d`, it could be shell variables too. you can use your shell script to set those values.

Comment: o.k so I just added a little for loop, the process is still fast at ~30 seconds for a 1.6GB file:
<code> for line in 338{66,69,72,75,78,81,84,87,90,93,96,99}; do (awk -v l="$f" -v d=34027 'NR==l&&$3>=-25&&$3<=25{p=1;next}p{print;exit}{l+=d}' HISTORY > newfile.txt) ; done </code>

However I'm still not getting any data in newfile.txt, can you think of anything else I can try?

Comment: sorry that was a little wrong:
`for line in 338{66,69,72,75,78,81,84,87,90,93,96,99}; do (awk -v l="$line" -v d=34027 'NR==l&&$3>=-25&&$3<=25{p=1;next}p{print;exit}{l+=d}' HISTORY > newfile.txt) ; done`

Comment: @sparxwil I think your `for` statement could have problem. what is `338{66,.....}`? read this see if it helps: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/

Comment: and, if your `for` worked, you are trying to do the task many times with `hardcoded d=34027 (difference)` in your loop, I thought you would set different `l` (starting line) and `d` (difference).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33350/discussion-between-sparxwil-and-kent)

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't have any input to test with, I am giving you an answer without testing.

```
tl=$(wc -l input)
awk '{
   for (i=33866; i<tl; i+=34027) {
      if (NR==i && $3 >= -10 && $3 <= 10) {
         getline;
         print;
         exit;
      }
   }
}' input
```

Comment: found match, then print **next** line :)

Comment: OP wants to check the file from a specific line, not from the first. this would be easy to be fixed. And if I understood your codes right, you are gonna do the `for-loop` for each line in input file?

Comment: @Kent is there any chance you could take a quick look again at my edits above? It wasn't letting me ping you in your answer, hence the comment on this one.